# Overlap datetime and sum detected

Tags: sql-server, overlapping

I'am trying to build query which can check overlap datetime, where I need to chceck records one by one. Here is my table:

```
ID_p    id_k    start                   end
1568    1   2017-09-11 13:32:59.000 2017-09-11 13:47:19.000
1568    2   2017-09-11 15:20:51.000 2017-09-11 15:26:28.000
1568    3   2017-09-11 15:26:28.000 2017-09-11 15:26:29.000
1568    4   2017-09-11 15:26:29.000 2017-09-11 15:26:40.000
1568    5   2017-09-11 15:26:40.000 2017-09-11 15:26:56.000
1568    6   2017-09-11 15:26:56.000 2017-09-11 15:38:24.000
1568    7   2017-09-11 18:13:24.000 2017-09-11 18:26:56.000
```

What iwant to do is:
find the overlap, chceck if first row from kolumn 'end' = "start" in row nyber 2. When I'll know which one just want to sum it, what I expect is here:

```
ID_p    id_k    start   end
1568    1   2017-09-11 13:32:59.000 2017-09-11 13:47:19.000
1568    2   2017-09-11 15:20:51.000 2017-09-11 15:38:24.000
1568    3   2017-09-11 18:13:24.000 2017-09-11 18:26:56.000
```

How can I do this? Could You explain me, please?

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all, please try to explain more about why you want those rows.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to add more details

Comment: You use the word "sum" but I think instead you're looking to "merge" rows which abut each other (end of one = start of next). Can there be a situation where the end of one is *later* than the start of the next, and if yes, how should that be handled?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, The main thing is: in source table "end" column at row number 2 has the same value like "start" at row number 3, till 6th row tha same situation, the "end" column value is equal "start" value 1 row below. What I want to do is to create new table where I'll have only 3 rows because in fact rows from 2 to 6 is a one timeline.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lag and Lead for this to get next and preview value of the row:

```
SELECT
LAG(start) OVER (ORDER BY ID_p) prev_start, start, LEAD(start) OVER (ORDER BY ID_p) next_start,
LAG(end) OVER (ORDER BY ID_p) prev_end, end, LEAD(end) OVER (ORDER BY ID_p) next_end
FROM your_table
```

and in where you can compare prev, current and next values. Maybe you will need to order by another column like start.

Comment: Thank You for answer, but I realised that I forgot to write which version SQL I'am using its 2008 thereis no lag and lead funtions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code: let me know if it works for all your records:

```
  --sample data
  WITH ABC
  AS
  (
  SELECT '1568' as ID_p,1 as id_k,'2017-09-11 13:32:59.000' as Start, '2017-09-11 13:47:19.000' as [End]
  UNION 
   SELECT '1568' as ID_p,2 as id_k,'2017-09-11 15:20:51.000' as Start, '2017-09-11 15:26:28.000' as [End]
   UNION
  Select  '1568' as ID_p,3 as id_k,'2017-09-11 15:26:28.000' as Start, '2017-09-11 15:26:29.000'
   UNION
  Select  '1568' as ID_p,4 as id_k,'2017-09-11 15:26:29.000' as Start, '2017-09-11 15:26:40.000'
   UNION
  Select  '1568' as ID_p,5 as id_k,'2017-09-11 15:26:40.000' as Start, '2017-09-11 15:26:56.000'
   UNION
  Select  '1568' as ID_p,6 as id_k,'2017-09-11 15:26:56.000' as Start, '2017-09-11 15:38:24.000'
   UNION
  Select  '1568' as ID_p,7 as id_k,'2017-09-11 18:13:24.000' as Start, '2017-09-11 18:26:56.000'

  )
   --actual query:
    SELECT ID_p, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID_p)as id_k,MIN(start)as start,MAX([end]) as [End]
  FROM
  (
  SELECT ID_p, id_k, start, [end], lag([end])OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(hour,start) ORDER BY [end]) as new_end
  FROM ABC
  ) as A
  WHERE DATEPART(hour,start) = DATEPART(hour,[end])
  GROUP BY DATEPART(hour,start),ID_p



    --output:
      ID_p  id_k    start                   End
      1568  1   2017-09-11 13:32:59.000 2017-09-11 13:47:19.000
      1568  2   2017-09-11 15:20:51.000 2017-09-11 15:38:24.000
      1568  3   2017-09-11 18:13:24.000 2017-09-11 18:26:56.000
```

Explanation in short: Using `Lag` function to aggregate the row that has the same hour value from `start`, the outer `WHERE` clause restricts that the hour of `end` should be the same as the `start`, then the rest of code does nothing just group by each set, and using the `ROW_NUMBER` for the increment column.

Comment: Tkank You for answer. When I'm trying to  execute query there is a error like: 'lag' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Mateusz, which version of SSMS are you using? I am guessing 2008? then you need to do the self join, check online alternative method for `LAG` or `LEAD`

Comment: Now I realised that I didn't say You: 2008, this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that will work in SQL Server 2012 & later...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    ID_p INT NOT NULL,
    id_k INT NOT NULL,
    BegDT DATETIME NOT NULL,
    EndDT DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID_p, id_k) 
    );
INSERT #TestData (ID_p, id_k, BegDT, EndDT) VALUES
    (1568, 1, '2017-09-11 13:32:59.000', '2017-09-11 13:47:19.000'),
    (1568, 2, '2017-09-11 15:20:51.000', '2017-09-11 15:26:28.000'),
    (1568, 3, '2017-09-11 15:26:28.000', '2017-09-11 15:26:29.000'),
    (1568, 4, '2017-09-11 15:26:29.000', '2017-09-11 15:26:40.000'),
    (1568, 5, '2017-09-11 15:26:40.000', '2017-09-11 15:26:56.000'),
    (1568, 6, '2017-09-11 15:26:56.000', '2017-09-11 15:38:24.000'),
    (1568, 7, '2017-09-11 18:13:24.000', '2017-09-11 18:26:56.000');

--==================================================================

WITH 
    cte_FindGroupEdge AS (
        SELECT 
            td.ID_p, td.id_k, td.BegDT, td.EndDT,
            GroupEdge = CASE WHEN td.BegDT = LAG(td.EndDT) OVER (PARTITION BY td.ID_p ORDER BY td.id_k) THEN NULL ELSE td.id_k END
        FROM
            #TestData td
        ),
    cte_GroupFill AS (
        SELECT 
            fge.ID_p, fge.id_k, fge.BegDT, fge.EndDT, 
            GroupFill = MAX(fge.GroupEdge) OVER (PARTITION BY fge.ID_p ORDER BY fge.id_k ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
        FROM
            cte_FindGroupEdge fge
        )
SELECT 
    gf.ID_p,
    id_k = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gf.ID_p ORDER BY  MIN(gf.BegDT)),
    BegDT = MIN(gf.BegDT),
    EndDT = MAX(gf.EndDT)
FROM
    cte_GroupFill gf
GROUP BY
    gf.ID_p,
    gf.GroupFill;
```

Results...

```
ID_p        id_k                 BegDT                   EndDT
----------- -------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1568        1                    2017-09-11 13:32:59.000 2017-09-11 13:47:19.000
1568        2                    2017-09-11 15:20:51.000 2017-09-11 15:38:24.000
1568        3                    2017-09-11 18:13:24.000 2017-09-11 18:26:56.000
```